# Does index.jpg work the same as index.php in a directory?

Tags: image, indexing

I was wondering if adding /images/index.jpg would work the same exact way as would a index page : /home/index.php

If so this means I could use a more discrete image: `<img src="/images/" alt="index image>`

Is this possible?

Comment: This depends entirely on how you configure your web server, but this seems like a horrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could if you configured whatever server software you use to default to that file. For example in Apache you would use the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html) option in mod_dir.

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.jpg index.jpeg index.png # etc..
</IfModule>
```

It's really not a great idea though, and would just make setting the site up on a different server configuration a pain for somebody else. It's best to leave things like this in the code.